# Google Analytics on mobile clients

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am looking for documentation of the protocol used by the mobile Google Analytics SDKs.

In particular I would be interested in:

1. open source library implementing the protocol
2. documentation on the protocol (wire formats)
3. any partial analysis carried out on the protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple HTTP protocol fairly well documented by Google itself. It's called the measurement protocol.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/